# If $\sum u_n^2$ is convergent the prove that $\sum(u_n/n)$ is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $\sum u_n^2$ is convergent then prove that $$\sum \frac{u_n}{n}$$ is convergent

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: I edited your post.  Cheers!

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz?

Comment: $\sum u_n^2$ converges $\sum 1/n^2$ converges.